# Nuxt js how to enable cors version 3.11

Tags: javascript, cors, nuxt.js

Hi All i wanted to enable cors in nuxt application and [tried this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14598) as a working solution but the [website](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-middleware) says a server side middleware should not return.
Can you please let me know if there is a way with out middleware approach ?

Comment: You have a cors issue with what exactly? What is the client and the server here?

Comment: The client is UI react application and server is nuxtjs application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask